# Visual Studio nuget Fails because of SSL

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

This is the below error I am getting whenever I tried to install Microsoft.AspNet.Cors package.

Error downloading 'Microsoft.AspNet.Cors.5.2.6' from 'https://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/Microsoft.AspNet.Cors/5.2.6'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

How I  can solve this?  How to download  SSL certificate for Nuget?

Comment: You should use the following https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json feed url for better performance. 

Can you please clarify what you mean by SSL certificate for NuGet? 
How do you know what the problem is from the above logs?

Comment: Could you please share entire log if it exists? We could not got any useful info from above logs. And have you tried open the url `https://packages.nuget.org/api/v1/package/Microsoft.AspNet.Cors/5.2.6` in the browser directly? And what is your project type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was very simple. I tried to open the URL in the browser and came to know that it is blocked in the organization. After giving the access it worked.

Thanks